# FlashDevelop actionscript 3 code maintenance - duplicate class names

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I use FlashDevelop - 
I am working on code in ActionScript 3.
I started working on a 72hour project for Ludum dare and afterwards decided to get a fresh start with a new angle on the same idea. So I named the folder - GameName2 . .

I always use the same 'project' for things I work on in ActionScript 3 because I have code in that project that is useful for my game ideas. For instance a basic controller class. Now in the new game, I want to again inherit from that controller class, however I fear that since the name I'll pick for the new class is a duplicate of the name I used in the first version of this game, this will cause future difficulties and confusion..

I was wondering if there is any way to use namespaces or anything else, so I could have classes with the same name in different packages and avoid confusion when I import the packages for a specific game..

Right now:

I have:

```
gamename.controller.GameNameController
```

and

```
gamename2.controller.GameNameController
```

Is there any way to keep things more simple and clean? Thanks

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this using an `application domain` which is documented [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html), I would also recommend you create a Library SWC for your own framework code, so you can just import a SWC for reuse.

There is a third party plugin referenced from the FlashDevelop site to help you [Export a SWC](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=3rd_Party_Plugins_FD4) from FlashDevelop.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes to a simple way to contain my framework without making the code too cluttered.